# Powershell script only works if window is clicked

Tags: powershell, scripting

This is the script which I created:

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms     
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"  
$ie.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com")
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.google.com" , 2048)
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.outlook.com" , 2048)
$ie.Navigate2("https://studer-ksg.intranet.koerber.de/de/nc/fritz-studer-ag.html" , 2048)
$ie.Visible = $true

start-sleep -Milliseconds 4000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{F11}')

do
{
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 4000
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{TAB}')
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 100
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F5}")
}
While ($i -ne 0)
```

It opens an IE window with 4 tabs in fullscreen and switches between them. When I start the script, the window opens but nothing happens until I click in it. How can I make this automatically so you only have to run the script and everything goes by itself?

Comment: My guess is System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait require focus. try adding `$ie.TopMost = $true `

Comment: I see you're now using my answer in your code, please can you mark it as accepted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring the IE Window to the front so it has focus before the  SendKeys will work:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.VisualBasic"

$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"  
$ie.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com")
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.google.com" , 2048)
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.outlook.com" , 2048)
$ie.Visible = $true

$IEProcess = Get-Process | Where { $_.MainWindowHandle -eq $ie.HWND }
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($IEProcess.Id)

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 4000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{F11}')

do
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 4000
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{TAB}')
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F5}")
}
While ($i -ne 0)
```